# How can I resolve this Twitter JS embed factory error?

Tags: javascript, twitter, embed

I have been trying to embed a list of Tweets on a webpage but it produces this error. I believe I've followed the docs properly, for both the JS [factory function](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/embedded-tweets/guides/embedded-tweet-javascript-factory-function) and [widget.js](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/javascript-api/guides/set-up-twitter-for-websites).

I haven't been able to find a similar issue elsewhere and Twitter doesn't seem to provide any documentation for this type of issue.

This is the part of the website that is supposed to generate the embeds:

```
<div id="tweet-container"></div>
<div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="widgets.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="organise.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    organise({{ tweets | tojson }});
  </script>
</div>
```

organise.js:

```
function organise(tweetList){

  for (let i = 0; i < tweetList.length; i++) {

    var newDiv = document.createElement('div')
    newDiv.innerHTML = '<div id="video-${i}"'

    document.getElementById("tweet-container").appendChild(newDiv)

    twttr.widgets.createTweet(
      tweetList[i]["url"],
      document.getElementById(`video-${i}`),
      omit_script=true,
      {
        conversation: 'none',
        align: 'center',
        theme: 'dark'
        }
      )
      .then( function( el ) {
        console.log('Tweet added.');
    });
  }
}
```

And widgets.js:

```
window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    t = window.twttr || {};
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

  t._e = [];
  t.ready = function(f) {
    t._e.push(f);
  };

  return t;
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
```

Then this is the error I receive:
[image: Error on the webpage.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea if this is documented anywhere. I couldn't find anything in the twitter guides that mention this.

The problem is that `twttr.widgets` is `undefined` (which I'm sure you realized) which seemed odd to me because it tells me that `twttr` is not `undefined`. So I wanted to see what `twttr` was and console logged it.

I noticed the object has a `ready` method on it that takes a callback so I tried this:

```js
function organise(tweetList){
    twttr.ready(() => {
        console.log(twttr.widgets)
    })

// ..
```

And now `widgets` is defined!

[image]

So you'll need to wrap the code inside of your `organise` function within a callback that you give to `twttr.ready`.

Might look like this for example:

```js
function organise(tweetList){
    twttr.ready(() => {
        for (let i = 0; i < tweetList.length; i++) {
      
          var newDiv = document.createElement('div')
          newDiv.innerHTML = '<div id="video-${i}"'
      
          document.getElementById("tweet-container").appendChild(newDiv)
    
      
          twttr.widgets.createTweet(
            tweetList[i]["url"],
            document.getElementById(`video-${i}`),
            omit_script=true,
            {
              conversation: 'none',
              align: 'center',
              theme: 'dark'
              }
            )
            .then( function( el ) {
              console.log('Tweet added.');
          });
        }
    })
  }
```

Comment: I believe that worked, thank you.